# Best way to automatically create a database schema in RedShift

Tags: automation, database-schema, amazon-redshift

What is the Best way to automatically create a database schema in AWS RedShift (from an SQL create script or similar input)?

Could not see such clear possibility in the AWS Redshift SDK/CLI. If AWS do not provide that, is liquibase the best 3rd party approach?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use the CREATE SCHEMA statement in a SQL connection. We use the `psql` command line tool extensively in our scripts.

```
psql -d my_database -c "CREATE SCHEMA my_schema;"
```

Note that you need to obtain an 8.x version of `psql` for best results with Redshift. Also note that the credentials have been set as environment variables.